Using the same docker-compose.yml to deploy multiple services, removes the other ones
I have create a Gitlab pipeline which should deploy a bunch of services running on the same Dockerhost of the same kind but with slightly different settings (other credentials and ports). Therefore i created docker-compose.yml
services:
   microservice:
     image: ${GITLAB_CI_IMAGE_TAG}
     container_name: ${GITLAB_CI_CONTAINER_NAME}
     build:
       ...
     restart: always
     ports:
       - "0.0.0.0:${GITLAB_CI_PORT}:${GITLAB_CI_PORT}"
     expose:
       - ${GITLAB_CI_PORT}
     ...

Now in my Gitlab project i have created a .gitlab-ci.yml pipeline file for the stages "config, build, deploy"
deploy:microservice-01:
  stage: deploy
  ...
  variables:
    GITLAB_CI_IMAGE_TAG: "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/microservice-01:test_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
    GITLAB_CI_CONTAINER_NAME: "microservice-01.domain.com"
    GITLAB_CI_PORT:              "8080"
  before_script:
    - echo -n ""$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD"" | docker login --username "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" --password-stdin "$CI_REGISTRY"
  script:
    - docker compose -f docker-compose.yml pull --quiet microservice
    - docker compose -f docker-compose.yml down microservice
    - docker compose -f docker-compose.yml up --timeout 120 -d microservice

deploy:microservice-02:
  stage: deploy
  variables:
    GITLAB_CI_IMAGE_TAG: "${CI_REGISTRY_IMAGE}/microservice-02:test_${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA}"
    GITLAB_CI_CONTAINER_NAME: "microservice-02.domain.com"
    GITLAB_CI_PORT:              "8081"
  ...

When i deploy the first microservice-01 everything works like a charm, but when i deploy the next one, the microservice-02, the docker compose down will shutdown the microservice-01, but why? My expectiation was that they act independently.
